# Create Directory Alias outside DocumentRoot Apache 2.2 on Windows 7

Tags: apache, apache2

So I have t Apache 2.2 running on Windows 7

my DocumentRoot is set to

```
DocumentRoot "E:/www"

and this works fine 
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
#<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
<Directory "E:/www">
</ Directory>
```

I wish to set an Alias  to a images folder on a NAS mapped to Z:

```
Alias /images "Z:/images/"
  #  <Directory "Z:/images">
  #    AllowOverride None
  #    Options None
  #    Order allow,deny
  #    Allow from all
  #  </Directory>
```

The server will start with the above but when i navigate to  Z:\images\index.html in a  browser

ie localost/images/index.html

ie get a 404 error
Not Found

The requested URL /images/index.html was not found on this server.

any suggestions what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Try using the `UNC` path to your mapped drive ie `Alias /images //<server>/<resource>/` like `//192.168.1.202/images/`

Comment: Hi @KristerAndersson I fixed it by adding absolute path to the nas like 'Alias /images "//MyNas/Path/To/images" ' Thanx for the suggestion BTW ip address didn't work